# unable to get auth token in flickr

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to access flickr services from android ,

to get the full permissions ,

first of all i fetched forbs using flickr.auth.getFrob method by integrating & converting in MD5

> secret + 'api_key' + [api_key] +
>   'method' + 'flickr.auth.getFrob'

i successfully got the frob , but the problem came when i request a authorized token by integrating & converting in MD5

> secret + 'api_key' + [api_key] +
>   'frob' + [frob] + 'method' +
>   'flickr.auth.getToken'

but unfortunately i am getting invalid frob , i don't why whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This auth stuff is really tricky for Flickr. In my code, I got a callback after the user authenticated, and was given a different frob than the response to getFrob (something like pnbhd://auth?frob=XXXXX). Then when I used this frob, it worked. I imagine this is the problem, since you're getting "invalid frob" and not an error having to do with api_sig.