# invalid frob when getting a token from flickr api

Tags: android, api, authentication, token, flickr

I'm using flickrj flickr API, but I can't get a token. I managed to get a frob, and i call the method that is supposed to give me back the token after the user have authorized my application, but I constantly get "invalid frob". Any ideas on how to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question with virtually the same title:

[Unable to get auth token in flickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889160/unable-to-get-auth-token-in-flickr)

The user reports the same issue you are having.  Perhaps the advice in that question can help.  I found this quickly by doing the search "[android] Flickr Api Frob"

Comment: I had already seen it, but unfortunately wasn't much of a help :\